# How the CPU knows if address of memory belongs to given process or not?

Tags: memory-management, x86

[image]

Above diagram presents Page Table Entry. I cannot see any PID there ( id of process). Why do I expect a such PID in this place? I wondering how the CPU knows that some process modifies another process's memory. I mean the following situation:

```
Process 1:
mov [ADDR], $2
```

and `ADDR` is any address that belongs to another process so the CPU will generate an interruption which be served by OS. OS in result ( for example Linux) will kill `Process 1`.

So, in that situation, how the CPU knows if address of memory belongs to given process or not?

Comment: It doesn't have to guess, every process has its own set of mapping tables.  The basic way an operating system achieves memory isolation between processes.

Comment: The CPU doesn't know that. Your OS(Operating System: Windows, Linux,...) keeps track of that.

Comment: This is why an OS has to change page tables on every context switch (by writing the physical address of a top level page directory to a control register).

Comment: Ok, now it is clear. I forgot that every process has own page table.